# SQL: SUB-QUERY in a JOIN statement returns 'Invalid Column Name' error

Tags: sql, join, subquery, string-agg

I have the following query where I have the following data:

| UPC | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| 0123 | Albany |
| 0123 | Birmingham |
| 0123 | Austin |
| 0124 | Albany |
| 0124 | Birmingham |
| 0125 | Albany |

And I want the output to be:

| UPC | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| 0123 | Albany, Birmingham, Austin |
| 0124 | Albany, Austin |
| 0125 | Albany |

The problem I am running into is that I am pulling from two different databases - A and B; The UPC comes from A and the LOCATION comes from B

So I figured I needed to use a JOIN with a subquery containing a `SELECT` statement where `A.FORMULA_ID = B.FORMULA_ID`.

This is the query I have come up with:

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(B.UPC, ', '), C.LOCATION
FROM
    [DBO].FSFORMULA B
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT A.LOCATION
     FROM [DBO].LOCDETAIL A) AS C ON C.FORMULA_ID = B.FORMULA_ID
```

But I am getting an error:

> Invalid Column Name 'FORMULA_ID'

It seems to be pointing at `C.FORMULA_ID`.

I can't figure out what's wrong so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not selecting the column `FORMULA_ID` in your sub query. You need to select the column otherwise you cannot join on it.

Comment: Your subquery aliased as `C` only seems to have a `Location` column - not a `Formula_ID` column. If you want to join on `Formula_ID`, you need to also select that column inside your subquery ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(B.UPC, ', '), C.LOCATION
FROM
    [DBO].FSFORMULA B
JOIN
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT A.LOCATION, A.FORMULA_ID
       FROM [DBO].LOCDETAIL A
    ) AS C 
    ON C.FORMULA_ID = B.FORMULA_ID
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your code did get rid of the invalid column name error.